# How can I delay the triggering of the first click in this jQuery auto advance script for a slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I work on this script for auto advancing my slider. When I load it, it immediately triggers the autoAdvance on load and the second image is animated to without delay. The triggering of the next ones works just fine. I already tried to add a `.delay(8000)` in front of the `.trigger` like so `$('#slider-nav .next').delay(8000).trigger('click',[true]);`, but to no avail.

Can you please help me where to put another setTimeout or corresponding and how? Or whatever makes the trick?

Here is the whole code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

var timeOut = null;

$('#slider-nav .arrow').click(function(e,simulated){

    if(!simulated){

        clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }
});

(function autoAdvance(){

    timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,8000);
    $('#slider-nav .next').trigger('click',[true]);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code a little bit would do it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

       var timeOut = null;

       $('#slider-nav .arrow').click(function(e,simulated){

          if(!simulated){

             clearTimeout(timeOut);
          }
       });

       //Modify your code like this
       function autoAdvance(){
           timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,8000);
           $('#slider-nav .next').trigger('click',[true]);
       }; 

       timeOut = setTimeout(autoAdvance,8000);
});
```

Comment: I already fiddled around with pasting that above the function, but as you made it it does not work, since the whole function is stopped and chrome developer tools says `autoAdvance is not defined`. You meant to just paste it between the two blocks of code?

Comment: That indeed did it, though I cannot follow quite through why referencing it after the function evokes a delay before the function. Great job done.

Comment: @dollarvar: in your case is an immediately executed function which executes the `$('#slider-nav .next').trigger('click',[true]);` **immediately** for the first time. In my answer, it declares a function but **not executes** yet, and then call `setTimeout(autoAdvance,8000);` to execute it after 8 seconds.